# how to convert a string into an array within a bash function

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a function in bash that takes a space delimited string and outputs the 1st word in that string. I tried

```
function myFunc { a=$1; b=($a); echo ${b[0]};}
```

but with

```
myStr="hello world"
myFunc myStr
```

I get no output.

if I replace a=$1 in the function definition above with a="hello world", then I get the expected result on applying

```
myFunc
```

result: hello

Also if instead of passing myStr as an argument I pass in "hello world" directly, it also works:

```
myFunc "hello world"
```

result: hello

I tried all kinds of indirections with the exclamation points, as well as the `expr` constructions but to no avail. Finally the following seems to work:

```
function el_index { alias a=$1; b=($a); echo ${b[2]};}
```

I would like to gather here all other possible ways to accomplish the same thing as above. In particular, is there a way to bypass the intermediate variable a completely, and do something like b=(${$a}) in the second statement within the function body above? By the way, the construction

```
b=($a)
```

splits the string stored in a into words using the default delimiter, which is a single white space.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't "get no output" -- you do get the first word of the string you passed:

```
function myFunc { a=$1; b=($a); echo ${b[0]}; }
myStr="hello world"
myFunc myStr
```

```
myStr
```

If you're passing a variable *name*, you have to indirectly expand the variable in your function

```
function myFunc { a=${!1}; b=($a); echo ${b[0]}; }
# ..................^^^^^
myFunc myStr
```

```
hello
```

---

Here's another technique: it takes the variable name as the first parameter, then overwrites the positional parameters with the words in the *value* of the variable. The first word is then the first positional parameter

```
firstword() { set -- ${!1}; echo $1; }
firstword myStr
```

```
hello
```

Comment: Oh nice! I thought I had to do !$1 for indirection of function argument. That's very useful to know.

Comment: Second one is quite hacky, but definitely worth noting for future situations:)

Comment: I would argue "hacky" -- for shells without arrays (i.e. /bin/sh) it's a useful technique.

Comment: Indirection is not present in the POSIX specification, so I don't think you can rely on indirection to work in `/bin/sh`. `zsh`, for instance, uses a different syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can get 1st word this way:

```
myStr="hello world"
echo "${myStr%% *}"
hello
```

And your function will be:

```
function myFunc { echo "${1%% *}"; }
```

Comment: You could also say `echo "${1%% *}";` (eliminating the use of variable).

Answer (score 0):

This seems rather simple if I understand you correctly.  I also think your method works.

```
    function myFunc1 { 
    a="${1}"; b=( $a ); echo ${b[0]};
    }

    function myFunc2 { 
    echo "${1}" | awk '{ print $1 }'
    }

    function myFunc3 { 
    echo "${1%% *}"
    }

    myFunc1 "Hello World"
    # Which prints out: Hello

    myFunc2 "Hello World"
    # Which prints out: Hello

    myFunc3 "Hello World"
    # Which prints out: Hello
```

Output:

```
    ./test.sh
    Hello
    Hello
    Hello
```