# How to write a bash function that returns the index of a word in a string?

Tags: bash

I tried the following:

```
wordindex () {
alias myStr=$1
myArr=($myStr)
cnt=0
for x in "${myArr[@]}"
do
        ((++cnt))
        if [[ $x == "$2" ]]
        then
                break
        fi
done
echo $cnt
}
```

but the behavior seems quite unpredictable. Also results are different on mac terminal versus linux shell. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You're making the same error as your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19386953/7552)

Comment: Do you mean the alias line? I thought it works as well?

Comment: So where is my mistake, Glenn the bash expert?

Comment: use variable indirection

Comment: I tried replacing alias line with myStr=$(!1) but got the following error:  -bash: !1: command not found

Comment: Not `$(!1)` but `${!1}`

Comment: Or, you know, don't pass a variable name to a function, just expand the thing before passing it. Indirection smells funny.

Comment: @glenn: Thanks for the correction. But still can't get it to work after changing to ${!1}. Always returns 0 no matter what the position of the word is in the string.

Comment: @kojiro: tried wordindex "ab cd" "cd" as well but got 0 for output:(

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any errors.  Make sure you're *not* using /bin/sh to run your script -- you have bash-specific things in there.

I would write it like this:

```
wordindex () {
    words=( ${!1} )
    for ((i=0; i < ${#words[@]}; i++)); do
        if [[ ${words[i]} == $2 ]]; then
            echo $i
            break
        fi
    done
}
str="hello world foo bar"
wordindex str foo
```

```
2
```

Comment: thx for pointing out the existence of /bin/sh; I had no idea about such sutleties:x